# Adding required email field to django when creating users with admin

Tags: django, django-admin

When creating/adding a user with Django admin; how can this be customized?

For example, currently, the username and password are prompted for. However, I'd like to customize this to also have other required fields, such as 'email'?

The Django tutorial isn't clear on admin user auth customization?

Answer (score 9):

1. Place this in your `models.py`.

   ```py
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   User._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
   ```
2. Run `makemigrations`.
3. Run `migrate`.

[See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#field-access-api)

Comment: This made 'email' field required for me in the admin add user page, like the original question was asking. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Does not seem to work on Django 2.0. Can you maybe link any documentation on this?

Comment: @caliph, I hope this will help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#field-access-api

Comment: @caliph, Do not forget running makemigrations and migrate.

Answer (score 6):

Example for adding email to form when creating a user. In project `admin.py` added the following:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password','email')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email')}
        ),
    )
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
except NotRegistered:
    pass

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Interesting.  The `add_fieldsets` attribute is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/), but not in the [ModelAdmin reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options).

Comment: The email is still not required after adding 'email' to add_fieldsets. The other fields are bold (required) but email is not bold. See monmon29's answer for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can customize the user admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import admin as upstream

# custom admin class for the User model, subclassing Django's one
class UserAdmin(upstream.UserAdmin):
    add_form_template = ...
    add_form = ...
    add_fieldsets = ...

# unregister any existing admin for the User model and register mine
try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
except NotRegistered:
    pass
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The parts I left with `...` are the customizations you need to do to change the way the admin prompts for user creation.

Look for the original code in `django/contrib/auth/admin.py` and modify to taste.